# Meteor Subscribe do not working with router.current().params

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am getting problems when I try to get an object from a collection, the subscribe function are not working as expected. For Example:

Client:

JS

```
 Template.Main.onCreated(function(){     
   var num = Router.current().params.taskid;    
   console.log(num);
   this.subscribe('getTransaction',num);
 });
```

Server:

```
 Meteor.publish('getTransaction', function(taskid){ 
   return Transactions.find({taskid:taskid});
 });
```

If I keep this as it is I cannot show anything, the value showed in the console is 9. However if I change the variable "num" for the explicit value: 9 it works as expected.

Do you know why the subscribe is not working on this case?

I really appreciate all your help about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may be the fact that the Router is not "ready yet" at the moment the template is created. Did you placed your subscription in the Route specific options (I think you are using Iron-router?):

```
Router.route('/getTransaction/:_id', {

    ......
     subscriptions: function() {

        // add the subscription to the waitlist
        this.subscribe('getTransaction', this.params._id).wait();
      },
    .................................  
});
```

You can find more options here: 
http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#wait-and-ready

If that is not working try to "delay" a little the subscription by using a setTimeout() function. Like this:

```
Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
  this.subscribe('getTransaction',num);
}, 100);
```